# TITokenField- duplicate records are coming,

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using TITokenField and now i don't want to enter duplicate records.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/titokenfield

User is able to enter duplicate records.

Can anybody tell me how to handle this.

Thanks